# Can not set PixelFormat on Cocos2d for android

Tags: android, cocos2d-android

I am trying to setup a rendering format with that function `CCTexture2D.setDefaultAlphaPixelFormat(Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);`

but it give me  an error

`cannot find symbol method setDefaultAlphaPixelFormat(android.graphics.Bitmap.Config)`

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Here you go , add this where you set your view
For 32 bit

```
 mGLSurfaceView = new CCGLSurfaceView(this);    
 mGLSurfaceView.setEGLConfigChooser(8,8,8,8,0,0);
 mGLSurfaceView.getHolder().setFormat(PixelFormat.TRANSLUCENT);
 setContentView(mGLSurfaceView);
```